# JSS Obj - refer value of property from another property in same parent obj

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I got a material-ui AppBar component that is position="fixed" so it sticks to the upper border of the window as a main manu bar. Components name here is "header" Its getting styled with this JSS obj.

Since the main container slips under the AppBar Component to top 0, when its position is fixed i need to margin-top it down right under the AppBar in order to have them positioned consecutively.

Preferably, I would like to set the margin-top to have the actual value of the AppBar height so I dont need to set it manualy. (also the AppBar height adjusts to its content, so it may be of variable size)

However I dont know how to do this, so I have to set the height/margin-top(main_container) manually.

At least: How do I make the main_horizontal_container.marginTop get its value form the header.height, so I only have to set it once?

Unfort, that does not work as planned - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined"

```
 const styles = theme => ({
      main_horizontal_container:{
        display: "flex",
        get marginTop () {return this.header.height}
      },
      header:{
        height: 64,
      },
      sidebar:{
        //flexBasis: content,
      },
      content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        minWidth: 0, // So the Typography noWrap works
      },
      toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `this` in `this.header.height` refers to `main_horizontal_container` which doesn't have `header`. Instead, you could extract `header` to a variable:

```
const styles = theme => {
  const header = {
    height: 64,
  };

  return ({
    main_horizontal_container:{
      display: "flex",
      get marginTop () {return header.height}
    },
    header,
    sidebar:{
      //flexBasis: content,
    },
    content: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
      padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
      minWidth: 0, // So the Typography noWrap works
    },
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  });
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks - wonder why there is no solution to refer to each other directly.